# Proving that an isometry between compact spaces is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I've recently attempted to prove that if $f: X_1 \to X_2$ is isometric, $X_1, X_2$ compact, then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

But before this, I have a few questions:

1) is this even necessarily true?
2) does an isometry have to be a homeomorphism? I've seen it defined as such, but it's not clear to me why it must be. Specifically surjectivity is a pain to show, as I've come to find. I think compactness is important here somehow but I can't quite figure it out.

Here is what I've got:

Suppose there is an isometry $f: X_1 \to X_2$. Clearly $f$ is continuous, for given any $\varepsilon>0, x,y \in X_1$ we can choose $\delta = \varepsilon$ so that $d(x,y) < \delta$ implies $ = d(f(x), f(y)) < \delta = \varepsilon  $, in their respective metrics. Injectivity is also clear, for if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $d(f(x), f(y)) = d(x,y) = 0$ implies $x=y$ by the definition of a metric. The existence and continuity of $f^{-1}$ is also now clear, for $f$ is injective and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are compact. Now we show that $f$ is surjective, and hence a homeomorphism.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that there exists a $p \in X_2$ such that $p \neq f(x)$ for any $x \in X_1$. Then there is some minimum distance $r = d(p,f(X_1))$ between $p$ and the image of $X_1$ under $f$. By compactness, we obtain a countable dense subset $\{q_1, q_2, ... q_n, ...\}$ of $X_2$. Constructing balls of radius $r$ around each $q_i, i \in \mathbb{N}$, we obtain an open cover of $X_2$. Then since $X_2$ is compact, $X_2 \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^N B_r(q_i)$. It follows that $p \in B_r(q_n)$ for some $n  \le n \le N$. Then since $f(X)$ is compact by the continuity of $f$, it is closed so that its complement $f(X)^c$ is open in $X_2$, and hence  $B_r(q_n) \subset f(X)^c$.

So at the end there I was just finding every fact I could, but I'm not sure if they'll be useful. I don't think uniform continuity will come into it, but then again I don't know.

Some guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: What about the function $[0,1]\to [-1,1]$, $x \mapsto x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to guarantee that $f$ is surjective; there are trivial examples that illustrate the point - consider $X_1 = [0,1]$, $X_2 = [-1,1]$ endowed with the Euclidean subspace topologies, and $f(x) = x$.